# why is this figure not a simplicial complex?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image: this]
Is it because the intersecting  free 1 simplex at bottom right. Would it be a simplicial complex if I removed that part?

Comment: The picture is ambiguous. Is this object a union of $0$-simplices and $1$-simplices? Or are there also $2$-simplices? Labelling simplices explicitly would make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Not just that. The fact that the triangle below is not given a proper structure of simplex must be taken into account too: keep in mind that any two simplexes must intersect in a face. So, it should be split in two triangles by means of an additional segment joining the midpoint of the side with three vertices with the opposite vertex.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Intersection of two simplex is not a simplex.

Comment: so if i put a point on where 4-7 and 5-6 intersects, would it now be simplicial complex?

Comment: You check the definition of simplicial complex and verify that, it then would be simplicial complex

Comment: @physshyp regarding that particular comment/question, see also G. Sassatelli's answer.